# Why does a file object still exist after it's been closed in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, irb

Is the object still in memory after it has been closed? If so, is that because garbage collection hasn't kicked in yet? It looks like it was just marked as deleted rather than actually being gone from memory. This was produced in IRB, if that could affect it at all.

Thanks in advance!

```
1.9.3p125 :001 > f = File.open("myfile.txt", "r")
=> #<File:myfile.txt>     

1.9.3p125 :002 > f
=> #<File:myfile.txt>

1.9.3p125 :002 > f.size
 => 122 

1.9.3p125 :003 > f.close
 => nil 

1.9.3p125 :004 > f
 => #<File:myfile.txt (closed)>
```

Comment: This is not something special about files. It is a general thing about variables. If at some point, `f` suddenly starts to lose its referent, then it would be a mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *object* still exists in memory after you close the file. Your variable `f` is holding a reference to it, so it can't go away yet. Just like any other object, you're still able to access it until all references to it go away.

Answer (score 1):

`f` is a reference to an instance of the class `File`. As long as the reference exists, the instance (object) won't get garbage collected. Now, this particular object happens to have a method called `close` which causes the file to be closed, but that does nothing to the reference `f`, which would need to be set to point to something else for garbage collection to kick in.

So, to get rid of the object, *like any other*, you have to assign something else to `f` — there is no special case for instances of `File` or any other class to zero such references for you. (And indeed it would be problematic if arbitrary methods could silently cause your reference to become `nil` and then cause an exception when you try to use it.)

**Edit**: Also consider the fact that you can check if the file is closed by calling `f.closed?`. If `f` became `nil` when closed (or sometime after being closed), trying to call `closed?` on the `nil` reference would cause an exception…

Comment: I suppose I thought File was different since there's a close method. Do you happen to know what the close method actually does? Is it just a flag to stop any further code from operating on it?

Comment: Well, obviously the `close` method closes the file. That is, internally the `File` object is basically a wrapper around the platform's file descriptor. But just because a method is called close doesn't make it special in the sense that it could somehow set the reference to `nil` without you knowing about it… For example, if you were to write your own class `MyFile`, how would you implement the `close` method so as to set the reference to `nil`? And how would the user of your class know that you did it, or that you did it only in that particular method? `close` is just a word.